# Does iPhone ( i OS 8) support location updates after force quitting the app..?

Tags: ios8.1

Does iPhone (iOS 8) support location updates after force-quitting the application?
As i am not able to get the location updates when i forcefully quit the app.

I have added background app capabilities of Location Updates.
I have added all the configuration for CLLocationManager.
I have added all the necessary authorization keys in the plist.
I am using startLocationUpdates and startMonitoringSignificantLocationChange methods.

Is there anything I am missing. Or is everyone facing this issue.

Kindly do not mark as duplicate. As i have tried all the other solutions on the relevant threads.